# How can I say that I have a played a key role in a company's growth?

Tags: resume, team-role, company

Basically I was an intern and the only employee at the company so I was the only front office staff. I was there to open and close the office when the boss couldn't, I would welcome and give information to potential new customers, etc
And the company did gain many new customers thanks to me Id like to say
Now I don't how to say it on my resume 
I was thinking about something like :
'Intern at XXX company 
- participated in the growth of a newly established company'

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

You want to QUANTIFY everything, and put it in the form of C.A.R. stories

Challenge
Action
Resort.

> "While I was an intern at XYZ company, we were short staffed, so I took on the additional responsibilities of opening and closing the office, and received customers when the CEO was unavailable.  Due to this, I was able to increase our client base by 20%"

Or something like that.  Or, as writers say, "Show, don't tell".  You want to be able to demonstrate the benefit you gave them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you say HOW you helped the growth, and by how much, especially if it is quantifiable.

> Was reliably the main customer contact in the office, greeting and giving customer information on llama grooming and how Llamas-R-Us could provide efficient service.  While I was at Llamas-R-Us, we grew on average by 40 customers a month and my boss said that 25 of them were directly because of my help, that he was only growing by about 15 customers a month before hiring me.

Only say that if it is true, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to think about this incredibly valuable experience. Claim, then proof.

Claim: I can sell.  Proof: I convinced callers to the office to become customers, resulting in 20% sales growth.

Claim: I deal well with the public.  Proof: the business thrived partially because I served as its telephone voice.

Claim: I do what needs to be done. Proof: During my internship, I took the initiative to answer the telephone when the owner wasn't available.

You obviously will word this in your own way.